# problemas con mayusculas en las rutas laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, url, rutas

Tengo un problema con las rutas en mi proyecto laravel.

Funcionan bien, pero no quiero que distinga entre mayusculas y minusculas.

Por ejemplo tengo una ruta llamada `Dashboard` si en el buscador escribo `dashboard` me dice que la ruta no existe. Osea que tengo que escribirla si o si la primera en mayusculas.

```
`Route::get('/Dashboard', [GeneralController::class, 'Dashboard']);`
```

Esto es asi? o hay alguna forma de arreglar esto?